# Font alignment problem in PowerPoint

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have one computer that has a strange font alignment problem in PowerPoint.

- It only happens in PowerPoint.
- It only happens when the font is Arial Bold (bold italics looks
  normal).
- It only happens with the capital letter "D".

When I type the "D" it overlaps with the surrounding characters. It sort of looks like the kerning pairs are messed up, but since it only happens in PowerPoint it doesn't seem like it's a problem with the font in general.

It happens on new and existing PowerPoint files, but when those files are opened on another computer they appear normal.

Any ideas on what would cause this problem? Here's an example of what it looks like.

[image: Font misalginment]

Comment: o.O That's weird.

Comment: Just curious if it prints that way too.

Comment: I have not tried printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird for sure.

Here's some things to try:

Have you tried rebooting the problem computer? :)

Perhaps try repairing PowerPoint (click the Office Button, click PowerPoint Options, click Resources, then Diagnose).

Ensure PowerPoint is up-to-date (click the Office Button, click PowerPoint Options, click Resources, then Get Updates).

Try removing and reinstalling PowerPoint via Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel.

Comment: All good suggestions but I was hoping to avoid he reinstall route.